# Created Datasnap as Windows Service with Delphi XE2 returns Error 1057

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, datasnap

I have created a Datasnap server as Windows Service following [this tutorial](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41330) successfully.
I can install it using the command line and adding /INSTALL. However, when I follow this same tutorial for Delphi XE2, I can't get the service installed (although I am Administrator).

It returns the following error:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Service "ServerContainer3" failed to install with error: "System Error.  
Code: 1057.
The account name is invalid or does not exist, 
or the password is invalid for the account name specified"
```

How do I get the Datasnap service working compiled with Delphi XE2?

Comment: Perhaps a problem with the login or password expecting a AnsiString and getting a Unicode response?

Answer (score 3):

When creating the service, ensure the property ServiceStartName is blank and so is the Password property. This will have the service Logon default to Local System account, which works well. If you want to use a specific account to logon when the service starts, enter this in the ServiceStartName property and provide the accompanying password in the Password property.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Isaac, had the same issue and leaving the service name blank  solved it.  For the main question, this isnt a datasnap issue, just a Windows Service issue.

Answer (score 1):

My best crack at it would be you being administrator - and your account does not have a password. A bit of Google-Fu reveals this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159925

I have created a few datasnap services without any problems - related to this anyways :-)